# Can't get success after posting a link on social media with flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, hyperlink, share, social-media

I have a link that want to post on facebook, Instagram and twitter feed but can't get the success after of posting on feed,
actually want to open a dialog box after get succeed response. 
have used [flutter_share_me](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_share_me) ,  [flutter_share_social_media](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_share_social_media/versions)  and  [share](https://pub.dev/packages/share) plugin.
but couldn't get response.
at last I used [flutter_facebook_login](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_facebook_login) to get response after posted link on feed.

flutter_share_me with share plugin:

```
shareOnSocialMedia(String socialMedia) {
    if(socialMedia == "facebookMedia"){
      // facebookLogin();
     FlutterShareMe().shareToFacebook(url:appUrl , msg: "FlutterApp").whenComplete((){
       alertBoxforWinAndShare(context,"plus 1 lap\n to share");
    });

    }else if(socialMedia == "twitterMedia"){
      FlutterShareMe().shareToTwitter(url:appUrl,  msg: "FlutterApp",).whenComplete((){
        alertBoxforWinAndShare(context,"plus 1 lap\n to share");
      });
    }else if(socialMedia == "systemMedia"){
      Share.share(appUrl).whenComplete((){
        alertBoxforWinAndShare(context,"plus 1 lap\n to share");
      });
    }

  }
```

**OR**

flutter_facebook_login:

```
void facebookLogin()async {
  final facebookLogin = FacebookLogin();
        await facebookLogin.logIn(['email'])
        .then((result){
          switch (result.status) {
            case FacebookLoginStatus.loggedIn:
              final FacebookAccessToken accessToken = result.accessToken;
                Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Facebook logged in successfully',);
                alertBoxforWinAndShare(context,"plus 1 lap\n to share");

              break;
            case FacebookLoginStatus.cancelledByUser:
              Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Facebook login cancelled.',);
              break;
            case FacebookLoginStatus.error:
              Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: '$result.errorMessage',);
              break;
          }
        })
        .catchError((error){
          Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: '$error',);
    });
  }
```

In short ,I want to  like this android tutorial [facebook-sharing-in-android](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/facebook-sharing-in-android/) in flutter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin 
https://pub.dev/packages/share_social_media_plugin#-analysis-tab-

```
try {
   var result = await ShareSocialMediaPlugin.shareLine("http://www.google.com");
   print(result);
} on PlatformException catch (e) {
   print("sucedio un error");
}
```